Problem of deriving time dilation in different way
I tried to derive the time deliation equation in different way,but I got a ridiculous result.
Could somebody point out the problem in my derivation?
The derivation in situation 1 (stationary source & observer) is
"The source and the observer 1 are relatively stationary.So the time ${t_0}$ measured by the observer 1 is ${t_0}$=$\frac{D}{c}$"
The derivation in situation 2 (stationary source & moving observer) is
"The observer 2 is moving away from the source with relative speed $v_0$. So the time ${t}$ measured by observer 2 is ${t}=\frac{D+L}{c}$ , $L={v_0}{t}$ , $t_0=\frac{D}{c}$.
So $t=t_0+{\frac{v_0}{c}t}$ , then ${\frac{t(c-v_0)}{c}}=t_0$ , and finally we get $t=\frac{t_0}{1-\frac{v_0}{c}}$"


Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

@Amit, I have type the text out. I apologize for the inconvenience.

There are many questions similar to this. A few notes: 1. Using a "longitudinal" light clock is trickier because you have to account for length contraction 2. You aren't analyzing a full cycle of the clock but comparing times of events that are spatially separated. But time dilation refers conventionally to relating proper time in one frame to coordinate time in the other. Please see this question for a derivation that uses the longitudinal version of the clock.

The time dilation equation applies only to a particular case, in which you compare the time between two events that occur in the same place in one frame with the time between the same two events in a frame in which they occur in two separate places. The arrangement you have sketched out is not such a case, so the time dilation equation does not cover it.
